# Brainstorming solution --- double emails being sent

Tags: multithreading, email

Looking for ideas on how to solve this problem. Here's the deal:

We have a company that is sending us files sporadically which sit in a directory. On our side we have a windows service that monitors that directory for any incoming files. Once the service runs and finds files it then executes code to start processing said files. The directory can have anywhere from 1 to n files in it at a time. So for example we may have 1000 files that appear in the directory and the windows service sees those files and starts the process to put the data in our database and send an email.

The process runs multi-threaded and asynchronously. It grabs a file, puts the data in the database and then sends an email to someone. The problem here is, when two processes are running and they both are hitting the same code, sometimes 2 emails can get generated for the same person. The method reads as follows:

1. Go to database and see if the contact that we have is there.
2. Yup he is there, okay, Check 'email flag column'... has an email been sent to him?
3. Nope, okay, so send him an email, and mark 'email flag column' as YES (bool).

What's happening is that 2 threads are hitting this method at the same time and reading the code at the same time. Both look into the Database and see that the 'email flag column' is NO. Then they send the email and mark the columns to YES. But since this is happening so fast, thread (A) didn't get a chance to mark the DB column before thread (B) read the column.

I've thought about putting in some code to 'wait' if two threads are back to back in this method. Like a LOCK. But we cannot do that.  The only solution I have now is to NOT send an email. and have a console app that runs at certain times of the day and sends an email to the people who have a 0 (NO) in that column. Once the email gets sent then we mark the columns as 1 (YES).

It may not be the best solution, and that's why I'm here, to get some of you spooky scary smart people to help me think of some sexy solutions.

Comment: If you are reading and updating a database, using transactions is the common and proofen solution for scenarios like yours.

Comment: BTW: SO is NOT a discussion forum; it is a Question and Answer site.

Answer (score 1):

You need a lock.

One way is to have the process move the email to a private folder (for that process) before starting to process. Only one process can move a file. There's your lock.

**EDIT**

If you decide to use a database to set a lock in the database, beware.

Unless you are doing some special PInvokes to get to the Transactional File System on Windows Vista, 7 or Server 2008 you'll always in danger of having a problem extending the transaction to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I'd update email flag at the moment it's being read - by either using SP or just moving select and update into the same transaction. If, for example, emailing fails then you can always return it back to 0.

Comment: SELECT xxx FROM yyy **FOR UPDATE** will set a lock in the database.

Comment: hummmm, so perhaps putting the SQL query in a USING (c#) or a transaction block may do the trick....?

Comment: C# `using` has nothing to do with database concurrency actually - database transaction is the one that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple processes and synchronisation issues, you need some kind of central lock otherwise you can't solve the problem. Somehow they need to communicate.

If you absolutely cannot the processes as you describe, try a central 'sync' server. [Redis](http://redis.io/) would do the job, it has atomic key operations. Get the process to set a key when it grabs the file, as soon as it opens it and set a key to say "I have processed this file and I am process id X". If someone else has the lock on that file, they cancel the process. Check again just prior to sending the mail to avoid further contentions issues in the time between opening the file and setting the lock

You can set keys to expire automatically after a certain time.